# How do I "return" from an expresion?

Tags: rust

This function works well: when it finds an adapter it stops and returns.

```
fn choose_adapter(instance: vk::Instance) -> Option<Adapter<vk::Backend>> {
    let adapters = instance.enumerate_adapters();

    for adapter in adapters {
        if adapter.info.device_type == DeviceType::DiscreteGpu {
            return Some(adapter);
        }
    }
    return None;
}
```

The following modification doesn't compile. Adding `;` to `Some(adapter)` makes it fall through and always evaluate to `None`.

```
let adapter = match {
    let adapters = instance.enumerate_adapters();

    for adapter in adapters {
        if adapter.info.device_type == DeviceType::DiscreteGpu {
            Some(adapter)
        }
    }
    None
} {
    Some(val) => val,
    None => panic!(""),
};
```

How can I make the latter expression work like the function?

Comment: `return` will raise the returned value to the function's return, not to the matched expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want

```
let adapter = instance
    .enumerate_adapters()
    .into_iter()
    .find(|adapter| adapter.info.device_type == DeviceType::DiscreteGpu)
    .expect("no discrete GPU adapter found");
```

As for your actual question, if you want to exit a for loop early without returning from the function, you need to use `break`:

```
let adapter = {
    let adapters = instance.enumerate_adapters();
    let mut found = None;
    for adapter in adapters {
        if adapter.info.device_type == DeviceType::DiscreteGpu {           
            found = Some(adapter);
            break;
        }
    }
    found
};
```

Comment: May I advise `expect` instead of `unwrap`? Doesn't change the semantics, but it's nice to have a reason...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I tried to match the semantics of the original code, but fair enough, edited the answer.

Comment: The former gives "temporary value dropped while borrowed" so I will use the latter one

Comment: @MacelaruTiberiu I don't have an explanation why you see that error, but I don't know your full code and the prototype of the `enumerate_instances()` function, so I can't really know what's going on there.